# Store result in a var instead of printf

Tags: php, datetime

I have this PHP script that gets the age from date:

```
$bday = new DateTime('1987-04-21');
$today = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
$diff = $today->diff($bday);
printf('%d Years, %d Months', $diff->y, $diff->m);
```

Now I don't want to directly **printf**, I want to put the result in a **var** to use it elsewhere. How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just replace `printf` with `sprintf` like this

```
$var = sprintf('%d Years, %d Months', $diff->y, $diff->m);
```

> Documentation [for sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store month and year in different variable then do like this.

```
$bday = new DateTime('1987-04-21');
$today = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
$diff = $today->diff($bday);

$years = $diff->y;
$months = $diff->m;

//echo $months;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data is in `$diff`, you should be able to use that variable everywhere you want. There is no need to store it in yet another variable.

You can use:

```
echo "$differ->y Years, $differ->m Months";
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution

```
$bday = new DateTime('1987-04-21');
$today = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
$diff = $today->diff($bday);

$years = $diff->format('%y');
$months = $diff->format('%m');
```

Answer (score 0):

This a sample :

```
<?php
    $dob=date_create("1987-04-21");
    $currentDate=date_create(date('Y-m-d'));
    $diff=date_diff($dob,$currentDate);
    echo $diff->format("%y years");
?>
```